# Twitter login code is not working

Tags: c#-4.0, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitterizer

This is my code, I am trying to connect to twitter but it is not giving error.
I am using Twitterizer2 dll in this project. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 public UserOauthTokens TwitterLogin(string ConsumerKey, string ConsumerSecret)
 {
        UserOauthTokens utk = new UserOauthTokens();

        try
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request["oauth_token"] == null)
            {
                OAuthTokenResponse reqToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={0}", reqToken.Token));
            }
            else
            {
                utk.Oauth_Token = HttpContext.Current.Request["oauth_token"].ToString();
                utk.Oauth_Verifier = HttpContext.Current.Request["oauth_verifier"].ToString();
            }

            return utk;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return utk;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/get/oauth/authorize) says that you **must** use https.

Try changing the line to `https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={0}`

Note the extra `s` in there.

Also, make sure you're using the latest version of the library.

Comment: When I was working with php code, am able to fetch the tweets. But i don't want to use php now.

Comment: Twitter's rules have changed. You *must* use HTTPS.